# Floating divs should remain vertically center even if multiple rows are formed on resize. how?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If the question doesn't make complete sense, this might.

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                              |
|                                              |
|   IIIIIIIII IIIIIIIII IIIIIIIII IIIIIIIII    |   Main div holding for divs.
|                                              |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

Screen resized:

```
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
|   IIIIIIIII IIIIIIIII IIIIIIIII    |
|                                    |    Divs get divided into 2 rows,
|   IIIIIIIII                        |    but still vertically aligned.
|                                    |
|------------------------------------|
```

Howwwww?
Thanks in advance!

---

Here's the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/mrpKV/

Resize the "result" are horizontally. 
Lets assume that the height of a single row is 10px and the height of the container is 50px. When all the links can fit in a single row, the links should have 20px above them and 20px below them. When the window resizes and the boxes make two rows instead of one, both rows should still be in the center of the container div. e.g, having 15px on top and 15px on bottom. (if there is no margin between the 2 rows.

Better explained?

Comment: Without a link or jsfiddle, we can only take wild guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you tweak the top position of the menu? Like so:

```
#menu {
    float:right;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    top:10%;
}
```

Comment: This won't vertically center them. Check the JsFiddle, you will better understand the question.

Comment: I deleted my old answer and suggested a new one. Hopefully I am on the same page as you know.

Comment: I managed it with some jquery. Is that okay? Or is it preferable to find a CSS alternative? Here's the js: `var menu = $("#mainmenu").height(); $("#mainmenu").css("marginTop", 50-(menu/2));`

Comment: mainmenu us the same as menu. I just summarized the id's on jsfiddle

Comment: @salmanhijazi I would think either one would be fine as long as the content is still accessible in the event that Javascript or CSS might be disabled. This is pretty rare but it can be an issue of accessibility. But really this applies to all things web related. It is more of an issue in regards to navigation though. In this case I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: @salmanhijazi I actually like your solution better. Mainly because using the top attribute can be tricky because it centers from the top border. Not the center of the element.